Recurrence relation from multivariable generating function
I am aware that, given a multi-variable linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients, the resulting generating function can be very complicated; in particular it can fail to be rational (even to be holonomic).
My question is much simpler, though: How to go from a given rational function $F(z_1,\dots, z_n)$ to a linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients? In the case of a single-variable generating function, the coefficients of the recurrence relation are just the coefficients of the denominator polynomial. Is it the same in the multivariable setting? 7
This would mean that the only obstruction to having a rational generating function in the multivariable setting hidden in the initial conditions, which seems dubious to me.
For example, what is the recurrence relation yielding generating function
$$
F(z_1,\dots, z_n)=\frac{1}{(1-z_1)(1-z_2)\cdots (1-z_n)}?
$$
(I vaguely understand that this isn't quite well-posed, because the answer depends on the initial conditions, which are complicated in the multi-variable setting.)

Let's say that
$$
F(z_1,\dots,z_n) = \frac{P(z_1,\dots,z_n)}{Q(z_1,\dots,z_n)},
$$
then you rewrite it as $F(z_1,\dots,z_n)Q(z_1,\dots,z_n) =P(z_1,\dots,z_n)$, and see that for arbitrarily large powers, only the left hand side matters, so if
$$
Q(z_1,\dots,z_n) = \sum\limits_{i_1,\dots,i_n} a_{i_1\dots i_n} z_1^{i_1} \dots z_n^{i_n},
$$
you get
$$
\sum\limits_{i_1,\dots,i_n} a_{i_1\dots i_n} f_{k_1-i_1,\dots,k_n-i_n} = 0.
$$
For example, $F(x, y) = \frac{1}{1-x-y}$ corresponds to $f_{a,b} = f_{a-1,b}+f_{a,b-1}$, which is known for $f_{a,b} = \binom{a+b}{a}$.
The obstruction to always having a rational function, indeed, seems to be in boundary conditions, as they have to be of particular form for $F(z_1,\dots,z_n) Q(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ to be a polynomial.
For your particular example, it will be
$$
\sum\limits_{0 \leq i_1,\dots,i_n\leq 1} (-1)^{i_1+\dots+i_n} f_{k_1-i_1,\dots,k_n-i_n}=0,
$$
which is just a PIE-like formula for $f_{k_1,\dots,k_n} = 1$.
